# Why doesn't "ifconfig" work on some of my machines?

Tags: linux, unix

Some do...some don't work.

```
ifconfig
-bash: ifconfig: command not found
```

Comment: What kind of machines are they? What distro?

Comment: Note that that error message indicates that the program couldn't be found, not that it didn't work. (There's a difference)

Comment: I highly suggest getting out of the habit of using 'ifconfig' on Linux machines - it is deprecated in favour of iproute2 (ip <command>)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this is when ifconfig is in /usr/sbin which is not in a non-admin user's path. Try:

```
/sbin/ifconfig
```

Comment: You can also modify your PATH variable to include /sbin directory.

Comment: Worked for me on Debian 7.

Answer (score 1):

Redhat-based distros don't include much in root's path for (imho, misguided) security reasons.  Add /sbin;/usr/sbin;/usr/local/sbin to your path, or just memorise where your commands are stored are and specify the paths when running.

Comment: And, IIRC, neither do Debian based.

Comment: Debian very definitely does Samix.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add to the path for security reasons (so as not to "expose" all executables in those directories) you could use shell aliases.